# Laptop Crash - Event 41

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, ssd, motherboard

I have just upgraded my laptop. Before, I had two same ram each 2GB DDR3. Everything was working fine. For 5 years without any issue!

So, decided to upgrade laptop. Bought a 4GB DDR3 ram, Alternate it with slot 1 and now total memory i have was 6GB. Tried to run laptop but didn't work. Some weird green & red lines appeared on screen and get shutdown.

They changed my ram with lower one and it's worked. Then i bought SSD and replaced instead HDD. and removed CD ROM and inserted HDD instead.

Everything was fine and smooth. 6GB memory,and SSD. After a week, that lines displayed suddenly, and rebooted. Each time i turn it on that moment, It's get rebooted and was fixed after couple minutes. I checked log and event was kernel power issue. Which i believe it's ram issue. So i decided to replace 2GB ram with newer 4GB ram. to have 8GB total.

Now i have two 4GB DDR3 RAM each 4GB. But now again the same thing happen to me with same event. I ran memory diagnostic but both ram seems to be healthy. Below some screenshot may helpful. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[Event-41 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaV5n.png)

[Weird lines Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLYBR.jpg)

[SLOT-1 RAM CPU-Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V06nZ.png)

[SLOT-2 RAM CPU-Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou7W4.png)

[Memory CPU-Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0BHP.png)

I'm using win 10 for laptop dell e6410 latitude.

Answer (score 0):

Seems no one here can help. For those who looking for answer, Seek it in below link.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/laptop-crash-event-41/a4e5c266-3544-45db-b4da-c63765dca15b?tm=1619511629096